# Which users completed a list: How do I query this in as few steps as possible?

Tags: mysql, database, list

I have lists, identified with `list_id`.

Each list has items in it, identified with `item_id`, and ordered with `position_int`, and assigned to the aforementioned `list_id`.

Now, I have a table called `completed_items`.
Containing a record for every `item_id` that each `user_id` has completed. For redundancy the `position_int` and the `list_id` are also in each row. 
If a row exists, the item has been completed by the user. Otherwise, no record exists.

How can I find out which `user_id` have *fully* completed which `list_id`? Specifically, I am wondering if there's ONE mySQL query I can use to get this dataset.

[image]

I am thinking for convenience reasons, and possibly performance, I'll create a table `completed_lists` containing `list_id` and `user_id` of each list that has been fully completed.

Seems straightforward enough that I should be able to create such dataset in one swoop, instead of going in and looping over a million nested loops.

Here's my current approach:

```
FOREACH list_id{

      array_of_items = [all, items, from, list, id];

      FOREACH user_id{
        users_items = [];
        push items into users_items
        if length of array_of_items and users_items is the same
        then create a row in completed_lists
      }

}
```

The reason I don't like this approach is because I'm making many separate queries to the db (get each item, get each user id) and looping a lot of times. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach might be to use count(*) and GROUP BY.
So you get a count of the number of answer rows per user per list in the completed table then join to a subquery which gets you a total count of items in the list.

Something like this:

```
select user_id, c.list_id, count(user_id) as list_count, case when item_total-count(user_id)=0 then 'Complete' else 'Incomplete' end as list_status 
from completed c
left join (select list_id, count(*) as item_total from items group by list_id) aa on aa.list_id=c.list_id
group by user_id, c.list_id, item_total
```

For your "bonus points" part, you would need to give more detail about the structure of the table in order to determine a rule to exclude newer entries.

If you have some sort of timestamp or index, you could use a dense_rank to get the first item by date per user per list for example.

Comment: I wish I could double upvote, thanks so much, I adapted it for my specific use case and it worked really well! :-)  Clever to use count, case, left join, and group in this configuration! So much better than my original approach of fetching data one ID at a time and then looping it...

Comment: No problem. Sometimes all you need is to look in a different way and the solution jumps out.